# Chrome "copy image" acting weird since Mojave update

Tags: google-chrome, mojave

Ever since I've upgraded my MBP 2015 to Mojave, Chrome's "Copy Image" option has been quite quirky.

Before the update, the option copied the image properly, and pasting it to websites/apps that support pasting images (e.g. Messenger, Word, and so on) inserted the actual image object.

After the update, sometimes the image URL is copied, sometime the image data is on the clipboard as Base64 encoded string (resulting in webpages and apps freezing when pasting). The only time I can get the original behaviour to work for sure is if I open the image on a new page, and copy it from there - copying from a webpage results in the "new behaviour" of randomly copying actual image, image URL or image as Base64.

This issue is not present in other apps (e.g. Telegram) - copying an image and pasting it anywhere results in the image properly recognized and pasted. This issue is also not present on Windows 10, using the same Chrome version and same applications/websites.

Is there a way to get the original behaviour from pre-Mojave?